# Environment definitions with arguments in \enddef

Tags: environments

I was hoping to create a custom proof environment where along with the qed symbol it also mentions what was the claim that was proved. I thought the following would work:

```
\newenvironment{myproof}[1]%
{\vspace{1ex}\noindent{\em Pf.}\hspace{0.5em}}%
{\hfill{\tiny \qed (#1)}\vspace{1ex}}
```

I thought `\begin{myproof}{Claim 42} ..\end{myproof}` would work but it doesn't. After some googling I figured that it was because the argument is not passed on to `\endmyproof`.

Is there any fix to this? Or is this just bad TeX?

PS: FWIW, I was writing down a proof and had a small claim inside. The QED on the claim was a bit misleading that the proof of the Theorem was done. So this seemed like a natural(?) thing to do.

Comment: Oh, I did not realise. I searched briefly for a similar question here and couldn't find this one. I should have searched a bit more before posting this perhaps. Sorry about the repost.

Comment: No problem, [some (not too many) duplicates are good](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) - they help others to find the right answer. I found it in the list of "Related" questions at the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\newenvironment{myproof}` command behind the scenes actually defines two macros: `\myproof` and `\endmyproof`. These will be called by the `\begin` and `\end` commands to do the job. By the way of how `\begin` and `\end` work, only `\begin` can pass any arguments to the underlying macro, and thus `\newenvironment` only defines arguments for `\myproof`.

You can work around this by defining a temporary macro in `\myproof` and using its value in `\endmyproof`:

```
\newenvironment{myproof}[1]%
{\vspace{1ex}\noindent{\em Pf.}\hspace{0.5em}\def\myproofname{#1}}%
{\hfill{\tiny \qed (\myproofname)}\vspace{1ex}}
```

(If you put this environment definition in a package file, you could name this temporary macro `\myproof@name`, to avoid usage in the document and clashes.)

Comment: I think that needs to be a `\gdef` to make it work...

Comment: Why? `\myproof` and `\endmyproof` will be executed in the same group (created by `\begin` and `\end`), if you don't manually stop and restart the group between.

Comment: You're right. I was doing this earlier and I had the `\def` inside another environment and the use of the macro outside it...